# Class that is both an IObserver<T> and IObservable<T>

Tags: c#, system.reactive

This might be too vague for SO. I need a simple example of a class that is both an `IObserver<T>` and an `IOservable<T>`. T are actually the same type.

`OnNext` will create an `IOBservable<T>` sequence itself. Although, `this` should be prevented from observing itself. In essence the observer part is subscribing to multiple observables, and aggregating their values and then in turn serving that aggregation to other subscribers of it.

Is it as simple as inheriting/implementing both `IObserver<T>` and `IOservable<T>` Or am I thinking of composability in the wrong way here ?

```
public struct T
{
}

public class ObserverAndObservable : IObserver<T>, IObservable<T>
{
}
```

What I would like to achieve is something like this. Imagine I have a list of oribiting satellites, each are owned by different nations of the world. I would like to subscribe to say, the US ones(or whatever combination is useful) then compute their average GPS positions.

```
//Satellites are constantly emiting realtime data
List<Satellite> satellites;
IOBserver<Satellite> observer = satellites.ToObservable();

IDisposable observable = observer.Where(x => string.Equals(x.Name, "USSatellite")).Subscribe();

//Now, compute the GPS average of the Satellites.

//This is not very fluent. There is probably a way to compose these
//functions using a lambda at the end to do the computation, which in turn
//can be subscribed to by other IOBservers...
```

Comment: you can't inherit interfaces, only implement them. I know it seems like nit picinkg, but using the correct terminology makes it easier for you to understand everybody and for everybody to understand you.

Comment: Huh? sure you can inherit from interfaces. At least mechanically that is what you are doing.

Comment: No you don't inherit an interface, you implement an interface

Comment: Make your class Generic if you want to use T, otherwise use a concrete type

Comment: The technical term in relation to interfaces is "impliementing", though. You can only "inherit" from an interface when writing another interface. In Java this distinction is clearer than in C#, due to the `extende` and `implements` keywords. However, C# also makes a difference there, as the inherited class must come first in the list after the `:`.

Comment: Let's not get hung up on semantics here.

Comment: I think the greater question is why do you "need" this? Having a class that implements both of these interfaces seems more like an exercise in academia than anything necessitated by a practical application of these interfaces.

Comment: @moarboilerplate wat? .... Have a look at [`Subject<T>` in Rx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229173(v=vs.103).aspx) this one is so useful that I sometimes add the nuget package just for it

Comment: @Ivan if `OnNext` will create an `IObservable` what do you want to do with it?

Comment: not create it, but generate its own sequence that can be subscribed to

Comment: imagine yoiu have 5 satellites that are observable. In one place, suubscribe to each of them, sum values to give the average reading, and serve that up as a sequence

Comment: `Subject<T>` is an object that is an observable and an observer at the same time. It sounds like you are just making a subject.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you are describing is called the Decorator pattern. Not only is it valid, but the vast majority of Rx.Linq is implemented with this pattern.

As to the question of if you SHOULD do this, I would say no. There already is a wealth of decorators in Rx.Linq. In most cases you should be able to use the Rx.Linq methods to compose the decorator you want, with the added advantage that those methods should handle the edge cases much better than your implementation.

The point of Rx is that you can handle events in a functional programming paradime. Therefore you should learn to use the monads that ship with Rx.Net as opposed to trying to construct your behavior using a procedural programming paradime.

EDIT: Here is an example way you could implement your average monad.

```
public static class Foo
{
    public static IObservable<double> GetAverageOfLatest(this IEnumerable<IObservable<double>> sources)
    {
        int count = 1;
        var sums = sources.Aggregate(
            (left, right) =>
                {
                    //count how many satellites you have.
                    count ++;
                    return Observable.CombineLatest(left, right, (l, r) => l + r);
                });

        return sums.Select(sum => sum / count);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you give an example or a link on how to compose these decorators to say subscribe to five IObservables, and then fluently do a computation that is also an IOBservable to other Rx queries? See my updated original post.

Answer (score -3):

Technically there's nothing wrong with letting a single class implement both `IObservable<T>` and `IObserver<T>`, but since each interface also implies a responsibility, doing so would likely violate the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

The only remotely useful case I could imagine would be a kind of "observer proxy", but that doesn't sound very useful.

Comment: there are plenty of good reasons - not only to be a "proxy" - for example let's say you want to wrap an `IObservable` so that new subscribers will get the last value (you might call this an **Behavior**)  -the way to implement this will surely need to be both ... same when you want to implement LINQ's methods - so overall just have a look at **RX** to see tons of such classes

Comment: -1 It would not violate the SRP. Most of the useful Rx classes are actually classes that implement both. A simple example of a class that implements both is the class responsible for `Observable.Select`.

Comment: If you want to provide the last value to new subscribers, you can use a BehaviourSubject or Replay(1). Implementing IObervable or IObserver yourself is not a very common scenario for _using_ Rx - regardless of how it's _implemented_.